# How to replace a UITableView by UICollectionView in a same UIViewController?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, swift3, uicollectionview

I have a UIViewController and this controller has a Searchbar. If I write something the search result will be shown on UITableView. when I will select one of the rows of UITableView , the UITableView will be vanished and UICollectionView will be appeared on same UIViewController.

Example: If I write f in Searchbar ,UITableView will show

```
feni
florida
france
```

If I press in france, details will be shown on a UICollectionView in same UIViewController.

one think I have thought to hide UITableView in DidSelectRowAtindexPath and will appear UICollectionview Programmatically ... but to design a cell of UICollectionview in Programmatically is not easy to me.

Please provide me any suggestion or tutorials that I can proceed.

Comment: You can design for collectionview and tableview in same viewcontroller using storyboard.And you can hide/unhide tableview/collectionview as per your need.

Comment: To set uicollectionview above uitableview or vice-versa is a good idea??? if I need any change in UITableViewCell which is under UICollectionView then Design seems a nightmare to me.  :(

Comment: but you can hide your collectionview or tableview for a while to change design in cell of tableview or collectionview vice versa

Comment: While designing UITableViewcell which is under UICollectionView..... where I will Keep/Hide UICollectionView in StoryBoard???

Comment: if you want to design tableview cell which is down side of collectionview then you need to hide collectionview or change the frame of collectionview for until you complete the design,then rearrange it as it before

Comment: At first I have to design UITableViewCell completely/Perfectly then I will have to put UICollectionView Above UITableview. In ViewDidLoad I have to hide UICollectionView and then I have to show UICollectionView after selecting one of the rows of UITableView. Am I in right Approach?

Comment: yes ofcourse its not wrong approch.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a storyboard with tableview and collection view and give storyboard identifier and load the storyboard according to the condition

```
    if (some_condition)
    {
       //UITableview storyboard
      UIStoryboard* storyBoard  = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"storyboardName" bundle: nil]; 
      ViewController* vc = [storyBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: @"Storyboard identifier"];
    }
    else
    {
      //UICollectionview storyboard
       UIStoryboard* storyBoard  =  [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"storyboardName For Collection"  bundle: nil]; 
       ViewController* vc =  [storyBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: @"Storyboard identifier for collection view"];
    }
```

Hope it helps !

Comment: You can load the second storyboard of collection view in DidSelectRowAtindexPath of uitableview which will replace your tableview. Since both the viewController is same. In ViewController you need to implement both the tableview and collection view